# Two different interpretations for the over-provisioning formula in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I found two interpretations to a formula used for over-provisioning resources in [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) when autoscaling.

According to the following two sources:

- [Autoscaler and over-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-running-cost-effective-kubernetes-applications-on-gke#autoscaler_and_over-provisioning)
- [Autoscaling with GKE: Clusters and nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNAWA6NkoBs&t=403s)

the formula:

```
(1 - buffer) / (1 + traffic)
```

where:

```
buffer: percentage of CPU buffer that you reserve, so your workloads do not get to 100% CPU utilization

traffic: percentage of traffic increase(expected) in the following two or three minutes
```

Will give you the value of a *new resource utilization target for the HPA* to appropriately handle the expected traffic growth while minimizing extra resources allocation.

So, for example, if you have the following values:

```
buffer: 15%, so you would get a CPU utilization of up to 85%
traffic: 30% increase in the next two or three minutes
target utilization = (1 - 0.15) / (1 + 0.30) = 0.85 / 1.3 = 0.65384615
target utilization = 65%
```

The interpretation from those two sources would be that **65% is the optimized target utilization for the HPA**. Then, you **get a 35% of over-provisioned resources** to schedule new pods in existing nodes while the Cluster auto-scaler(and node auto-provisioner) will allocate new nodes during a peak in demand.

The problem is that the laboratory [Understanding and Combining GKE Autoscaling Strategies](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/15636?parent=catalog) in the section ["Optimize larger loads"](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/15636?parent=catalog#step11) (version: Manual Last Updated: March 19, 2021) establishes that the 65% value would be the percentage of over-provisioned resources you need to allocate in excess.

So, according to the first two sources:

- percentage of resources to overprovision: 35%

But according to the laboratory "Understanding and Combining GKE Autoscaling Strategies":

- percentage of resources to overprovision: 65%

Which one is the correct interpretation?

IMHO, the correct interpretation is that the value of over-provision equals 35%. The formula gives you a new resource utilization target for the HPA concerning the (new) traffic demand (and not the percentage of resources to allocate in excess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first interpretation is correct. In the first interpretation, they compute over-provisioning as the unused resources over the total size of the cluster, since Horizontal Pod Autoscaling is configured to keep resource utilization to ~65%, you have a 100% - 65% = 35% unused resources which is the value of a new target resource utilization for the HPA.

In the second interpretation i.e., "Understanding and Combining GKE Autoscaling Strategies", they seem to consider "over-provisioning percent" as how much more computing power is added to the “needed" compute resources. In other words, you have a 3 node cluster, needed to run your workload, and you add 2 nodes on top, this makes it such that you have over-provisioned the cluster by 2/3 = 66.6666% ~= 65%.

The first interpretation is more intuitive and makes more sense in practical usage.